# Bug in Windows's FindFirstFile() function?

Tags: winapi, file, file-io, wildcard

Why does calling [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418.aspx) with the pattern `*.*` match a name like `Windows`?

**Edit:** I guess I can also *guess* what's happening, but is there any documentation on the reason as well?

Comment: perhaps it's nothing more than `*` matching the empty string. Try `*.?*` say to match non empty extension

Comment: @David: But what if the file name ends in a period?

Comment: You're mentioning that `*` might match the empty string, but that only works if the file name ended in a period. `Windows` doesn't end in a period, so why should it match?

Comment: its short name has a period. All shortnames do.

Comment: maybe you should read the source code for Wine and at least you'd learn the algorithm if not the rationale behind it

Comment: @David: I'll take a look when I take a chance, okay, but the short name reason isn't really correct, because like I mentioned, the short names *don't even exist* on my volume.

Comment: in the absence of documentation we have to guess

Comment: did you read Raymond's blog post linked from one of your answers. That seems to explain it.

Comment: @David: Nope, I hadn't seen the revision; that explains it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the blog post ['How did wildcards work in MS-DOS?'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx) Raymond Chen describes how the original DOS wildcard matching was implemented. At the end of the post he points out how `*.*` is handled as a special case in the Win32 wildcard matching algorithm.

A quote from the post

`For example, if your pattern ends in .*, the .* is ignored. Without this rule, the pattern *.* would match only files that contained a dot, which would break probably 90% of all the batch files on the planet, as well as everybody's muscle memory, since everybody running Windows NT 3.1 grew up in a world where *.* meant all files.`

Answer (score 1):

`*.*` matches everything in the target directory.

This is because `*.` matches up to the final period; if there is *no* period in the name then that name is treated as if it ended in a period; so `*.` matches only names beginning with a period and names containing no period (`.afile / adirname`) if you add a `*` on the end for `*.*` then it also matches beyond the final period so includes file names containing a period, this covers all possible file names.