# Directory.GetDirectories returns wrong results with a pattern of *.*

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

Assume you have a directory that contains the following directories:

> dontgetme
> get.me

If you use the following code:

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

You would expect `directories` to contain:

> get.me

But it contains both directories, why is this?

Looking into the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the only wildcards are `*` and `?` so they shouldn't be affecting this.

Further if you use the pattern `*.` only the `dontgetme` directory is returned; but using `*.*.*.*` etc. both are still returned.

---

In case it matters I am using .NET 4.6.1 and C# 6 on Windows 10.

Comment: Windows file and directory names always have an extension so `*.*` matches `anything` because it's treated as `anything.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this comes down to a compatibility decision.  Ultimately C# will end up calling the Win32 [FindFirstFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) method to do the search.

Looking into this, I actually found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6167736/2779530) that explains it.

I'll repeat the quote from that answer (taken from [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx)):

> For example, if your pattern ends in `.*`, the `.*` is ignored. Without this rule, the pattern *.* would match only files that contained a dot, which would break probably 90% of all the batch files on the planet, as well as everybody's muscle memory, since everybody running Windows NT 3.1 grew up in a world where `*.*` meant all files.

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6167713/4631427) to the same question also explains the behaviour involving `*.` (emphasis mine):

> `*.*` matches everything in the target directory.
>
> This is because `*.` matches up to the final period; if there is *no* period in the name then that name is treated as if it ended in a period; **so `*.` matches only names beginning with a period and names containing no period** (`.afile / adirname`) if you add a `*` on the end for `*.*` then it also matches beyond the final period so includes file names containing a period, this covers all possible file names.

Comment: Nice find, I'm guessing this is iterative then and that explains the `*.*.*.*.*` behaviour? It doesn't really explain the `*.` behaviour though....

Comment: The other answer explains the `*.` behaviour

Answer (score 3):

You pattern means "anything with any extension". *No* extension **is** "any extension", so you match all four.

You could try `?*.?*` as pattern so you get those that have at least one character as both extension *and* name.

Comment: But surely it should be looking for the literal `.` in the name? Or are the directory names essentially `yes.please.`?

Comment: ever thought of '.\nope' as the local name of that dir?

Comment: Actually, I'm beginning to doubt my own answer too as a pattern of `*.*.*.*.*.*` will also match all directories...

Comment: @DavidG See my edit it also acts differently if you pass in `*.`

Comment: If you use the `?*.?*` pattern both are still returned as `?` is zero or one.

Answer (score 2):

Windows file and directory names always have an extension, even if it's blank. So `*.*` matches `anything` because it's treated as `anything.`

Comment: Did you find anything extra out about this, especially the `*.*.*.*.*.*...` patterns?

Comment: I'm just digging around now, unfortunately it's all buried in the Win32 API...

Comment: The answer by @Kyle points to a duplicate that explains this behaviour, I've marked my question as a dupe. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Aww, I was having fun digging around the API docs!

Comment: By all means carry on if you wish, I'm not going to stop you!