# C# Directory EnumerateFiles: the difference between masks "*.*" and "*"?

Tags: c#, filesystems

I'm using the function `Directory.EnumerateFiles` to enumerate all files in a directory.

I use search pattern `"*"` but in many examples, I see the pattern `"*.*"`

My question: what is the difference between masks `"*.*"` and `"*"`?

Comment: `"*.*"` means any file name with any extension, while `"*"` means any file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be the same, at least in .Net Framework.

From reference sources of [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/17b97365645da62cf8a49444d979f94a59bbb155/mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs#L902), it uses `FindFirstFile` WinAPI function underneath (from [this](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/3b1eaf5203992df69de44c783a3eda37d3d4cd10/mscorlib/system/io/filesystemenumerable.cs#L273) part of reference sources).

`FindFirstFile` includes files with no extensions into `*.*` search pattern (more detailed in this question [Bug in Windows's FindFirstFile() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166394/bug-in-windowss-findfirstfile-function) ). So the same way as with `*` mask - all the files with any extension even with empty extension.

Answer (score 0):

The "*" means any file, "*.*" means: the first * is any file name and the second means any extension of this filename.